# Reverse a string using while(),pop() and insert

Tags: python-3.x

using

```
while
.pop()
insert()
```

pop() the first item in the list and add to the beginning of a new string that will be reversed

```
# [ ] Challenge: write the code for "reverse a string" reversing some_numbers

some_numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77]

rev_string = []

while len(some_numbers):
    rev = some_numbers.pop()
    rev_string.insert(0,rev)
print(rev)

print(some_numbers)
print(rev_string)
```

My first question is that:

1. As i am printing rev in line 7, i am getting 1 as the answer but we know that an empty pop is used to denote the last element then why i am getting 1 instead of 77.
2. I am getting the right answer by putting 0 inside the pop in line 5. How ?

Comment: `but we know that an empty pop is used to denote the last element` that sounds wrong. What makes you say that?

Comment: If you want to reverse the list shouldn't you be inserting new items at the end: `rev_string.insert(len(rev_string), rev)` (identical to `append`). Also you will never try to `pop` on the empty list. Your loop stops when `some_numbers` is empty

Comment: as for why you're getting the right answer, `pop` by default pulls out the last element. but `pop(0)` pulls the element at 0th index aka first position. as fyi, this is all grossly inefficient.

Comment: A little more effort prior to posting would have revealed the answer. I didn't remember off the top of my head what exactly `pop()` and `insert()` did, so I copied your code, pasted it into an interpreter, and started fiddling around with `some_numbers`, `pop()`, and `insert()`. It would have been impossible not to figure it out had you done so. Asking on SO isn't your first option, before you investigate. It's your last option, after you investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption `pop() the first item in the list` is wrong. When you call `some_numbers.pop`, you get the **last** element of the list popped, check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). This should answer both of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

pop() without parameters returns and then deletes the last element but you are assuming just the opposite. you should use

```
del listname[0]
```

But note this simply deletes (does not return and delete like pop)
so use

```
listname[0]
```

to access your element beforeusing del

Answer (score 0):

1.**rev** equals to **77** at the first while iteration. since you are looping until 
len(some_numbers) **rev** equals to **1** in the end of the loop.

2.The **pop** function gets index as input, which means if u put 0 inside the pop, every iteration it pops the index 0 in the list. And leaves you with the last number of the list at the end of the loop.