# Python3: Reverse a list using only while, .pop() and .insert()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do the following exercise:

> ## Challenge: reverse a list using while .pop() insert() pop() the first item in the list and add to the beginning of a new string that will be reversed
>
> some_numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77]

Here's the code I have written:

```
some_numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
new=[]
while some_numbers:
    x=some_numbers.pop() #Should delete the last item on the list
    new.insert(-1,x)     #Should insert it in -1 position on the list
print(new)
```

However, this is the result I am getting:

```
[66, 55, 44, 33, 22, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 77]
```

Does somebody know how can I make the "77" at the beginning on the list? I tried populating new=[" "] and it works but obviously the space appears as part of the list in the result and I just want the numbers there. Thanks!!

Comment: [Exactly the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653438/reverse-a-string-using-while-pop-and-insert).

Comment: See my answer for explanation as to why your answer does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting at `len(reverse)`:

```
some_numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77]

reverse = []
while some_numbers:
    reverse.insert(len(reverse), some_numbers.pop())

print(reverse)
```

**Output**

```
[77, 66, 55, 44, 33, 22, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of
>   the element before which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the
>   front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to
>   a.append(x).

Notice that:

> The first argument is the index of the element **before** which to
>   insert

When you do `insert(-1, x)`, your code inserts before the last element, for example if you print `reverse` at each stage, you get:

```
[77]
[66, 77]
[66, 55, 77]
[66, 55, 44, 77]
[66, 55, 44, 33, 77]
[66, 55, 44, 33, 22, 77]
...
```

Comment: Many thanks! I understand this approach, but do you know why mine is not working properly?

Comment: This clearly works. But according to the question, this was supposed to be done by repetitively popping the first number and then inserting it at the *front* of the resulting list,  which is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Always pop the first item of `some_numbers` and insert it at the beginning of the new list, which is what the question stated was to be done:

```
>>> some_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
>>> new = []
>>> while some_numbers:
...     new.insert(0, some_numbers.pop(0))
...
>>> new
[77, 66, 55, 44, 33, 22, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

**Why the OP's Answer Does Not Work**

`new.insert(-1, 3)` inserts `3` *before* the last element of `new`. When `new` is empty, `3` is just inserted and we have `[3]` as the result. But subsequent insertions are inserted before the last element, which is `3`. Thus, the first element inserted will always be the last element of the final list. In the example below, that will be the number `3`:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.insert(-1, 3)
>>> l
[3]
>>> l.insert(-1, 2)
>>> l
[2, 3]
>>> l.insert(-1, 1)
>>> l
[2, 1, 3]
>>>
```

So instead of reversing `1, 2, 3` to get `3, 2, 1`, we end up with `2, 1, 3`. `3` should have been at the beginning of the final result but it is instead at the end because it was the first item inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You can solove this challenge using with a single variable(i):

```
some_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]
new = []
i = 0
while some_numbers:
    x = some_numbers.pop()  # Should delete the last item on the list
    new.insert(i, x)  # Should insert it in -1 position on the list
    i += 1
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the following list using python without using a list-reversed function. what about this?

```py
List_new=[22 , 33 ,44 ,55 ,66 ,77 ,88]
```